# Removing certain string that are not a part of different string?

Tags: c#, string

I have been wrestling with strings in Unity but currently, I have no idea what to do.

The thing is, Unity uses merely /n for new line while most texts that are going to be placed in the db uses /r/n. There isn't much trouble IF things are done without touching them but if I remove a newline and merge two strings to a single line in Unity, /r is always left there.

Normally, this would not cause any problems as they will be simply ignored, however, I'm trying to add few features to its text.

In short : How to remove /n and /r in "there is/r no/r/n cow/n level" without removing /r/n?

Comment: how about regex to select and replace all occurrences of `\r` that are not followed by `\n` ?

Comment: Why don't remove /r initially, when "I remove a newline and merge two strings to a single line in Unity"?

Comment: @Andrei Well, I can't do that as I need to fix strings (setting up texts) in run time or at least in the editor. As I have explained above, doing a simple backspace in Unity's inspector text does not remove \r as it is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming that you're actually talking about `\r` and `\n` since you mention "new lines")

**The Easy (or Fast) Way**

```
s.Replace("\r\n", @"\/r\/n").Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","").Replace(@"\/r\/n","\r\n")
```

This will work if you have no `"\/r\/n"` in your string, which is probably true

**The Regex (or Safe) Way**

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "\r([^\n])", "$1");
s = Regex.Replace(s, "([^\r])\n", "$1");
```

In the pattern regexes, the `[^\r]` and `[^\n]` are captured with the parenthesis `( )` and you can reuse this capture in your replace, that's the meaning of these `$1` bits

Comment: the first way assumes that /r/n is never valid, as long as that assumption is correct this will work (and will probably be faster)

Comment: @Kevin yep exactly... I should rename the sections: The fast way vs. the safe way

Comment: Oh, I have a habit picked up long way ago that keeps me writing /n instead of \n. Sorry about that.

Comment: Anyhow, thanks. I really need to do some work on Regex.

Answer (score 2):

A Regex Replace will help you

```
var input = "there is/r no/r/n cow/n level";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!(/n)|(/r))((/n)|(/r))(?!(/n)|(/r))", String.Empty);
```

This says match any /r or /n that is not preceeded, or followed, by an /r or /n.